# Moodle 2.7, scorm 1.2 - how to capture cmi.core.session_time from the SCORM in Moodle?

Tags: php, moodle, scorm

In Moodle 2.7, scorm 1.2 writes the cmi.core.session_time (can see it in the SCORM tracking tool) but that value is not stored in the DB in Moodle (the only value stored is cmi.core.total_time).

is there a way to get the session_time value via events in Moodle?

Comment: Off topic, but please consider upgrading your Moodle installation. I know 2.7 is LTS and is still supported, but that support is due to end very soon (ie [within the next couple of weeks](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Releases)).

Answer (score 3):

According to the specification when LMSFinish() is called at the end of the session, the value in the cmi.core.session_time element should be added to the value stored in the cmi.core.total_time element, and the value in the cmi.core.session_time element should be reset. To get the value you can use a script in the LMSFinish() function and get the value of cmi.core.session_time before resetting.
Hope this will help.

Comment: This is correct -- SCORM does not store session time, therefore a prior session's time is unavailable when querying from a subsequent session. You can only retrieve the cumulative time.